# PDO - Class Not Found

Tags: php, pdo

## O que está acontecendo

Criei um método estático para retornar a conexão para que  eu possa usá-la no DAO, mas ao fazer isso ele dá **Class Not Found PDO**.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Outros Projetos

A primeira coisa que muita gente vai pensar é: "A extensão não está ativada". Senhores, as extensões estão devidamente ativadas e já foram usadas em outros projetos. Eu tenho aqui outros 2 projetos com o PDO, mas dessa vez eu tentei usar da Orientação a Objeto da melhor forma possível, para deixar o código mais clean.

**OBS:** Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão para deixar alguma classe mais 'bonita', estarei aberto a modificações.

## PDO Ativo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Meu Código

#### Class EntidadeDAO

```
<?php

namespace Presto\model;
use Presto\model\ConnectionFactory as ConnectionFactory ;

class EntidadeDAO {
    private $connection = null;

    public function __construct() {
        self::$connection = ConnectionFactory::getConnection();
    }
}
```

#### Class ConnectionFactory

```
<?php
namespace Presto\model;

class ConnectionFactory {

public static function getConnection() {
    $connection = null;
    $config = self::configureConnection();

    try {
        self::$conection = new PDO($config['databaseType'].':host='.$config['hostname'].';dbname='.$config['database'],$config['username'],$config['password']);
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    return self::$connection;
}

public static function configureConnection() {
    $config = array();

    $config['databaseType'] = 'pgsql';
    $config['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
    $config['database'] = 'minhaDatabase';
    $config['username'] = 'root';
    $config['password'] = 'password';

    return $config;
}
}
```

Comment: Coloca o print do phpinfo com a parte do PDO, so p deixar bem claro que a extensão foi instalada e eliminar essa possibilidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saiba interpretar o erro **\Presto\model\PDO** not found, quando se trabalha com namespace, cada barra invertida é um diretório correto?

Para usar a lib PDO ou bibliotecas nativas que precisa se instanciadas, use a barra invertida antes, pois apontara para raiz, ou seja, as bibliotecas nativas do PHP.

Exemplo: **\PDO**

```
public static function getConnection() {
    $connection = null;
    $config = self::configureConnection();

    try {
        self::$conection = new \PDO($config['databaseType'].':host='.$config['hostname'].';dbname='.$config['database'],$config['username'],$config['password']);
    }catch (\PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    return self::$connection;
}
```

Comment: Ele está mostrando Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Presto\model\ConnectionFactory::$connection in C:\wamp\www\TestePHP\app\Presto\model\ConnectionFactory.php on line 16. Acesso a uma propriedade estático não declarada. Eu coloquei static antes de $connection e o erro permaneceu. Saberia qual é a resolução ?

Comment: @AllanRamos não faz sentido utilizar Singleton com banco de dados, uma conexão não deve ser estendida, ela deve ser apenas utilizada, sua ConnectionFactory está limitada a uma só conexão. 

Para corrigir isso, [injete os dados](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) de acesso, e perpetue a instância da forma correta através da sua aplicação. Seja por injeção de dependência ou Registry.

Mas caso queira usar assim mesmo, de uma olhada [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381573/php-static-v-singleton-class-connectionfactory-explained?answertab=oldest#tab-top)